Not filter records after active admin and ransack updation
I have recently updated activeadmin and ransack gem, below code snippets is working fine with active admin and ransack gem using version :
active admin- 2.13.1
ransack: >= 2.1 , < 4
when I updated both version as:
**active admin: 3.2.1
ransack: >= 4.0
**
We could not get filtering by
`
 filter :Post, as: :select, collection: proc { Post.pluck(:name, :id).uniq }


we are getting as  undefined method `post_id_eq' for Ransack::Search

What I tried:

filter :post, as: :select, collection: proc {Post.pluck(:name, :id).uniq },        filters: [:eq]

2 filter :post_id, as: :select, collection: proc {Post.pluck(:name, :id).uniq }, filters: [:eq]
